# How to select mysql columns to insert multiple check box values using for loop

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have 3 checkboxes:

```
<input name="perm[0]" type="checkbox" value="1" />
<input name="perm[1]" type="checkbox" value="1" />
<input name="perm[2]" type="checkbox" value="1" />
```

Im using a for loop to iterate through the array as follows:

```
for($i=0; $i < 3; $i++)
{
    $perm[$i] = isset($_POST[$perm][$i]) ? 1 : 0;
}
```

Earlier I created the 3 columns successfully `uread`, `uwrite` and `usearch`.
i would like to insert the data from perm[0] into uread,perm[1] into uwrite and so on,i don't know how to do that using a single INSERT statement.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't understand your question, what do you mean "select the respective table column in each iteration to insert the values?"

Comment: @Revent I think OP want generate dynamic query with varying columns, depending on selected checkboxes.

Comment: if there is only three of them, then why don't you use direct names instead of `perm[]` in your markup ?

Comment: if CORRUPT's statement is correct: you could have save column names (as values) and checkbox names (as keys) in an array and make an insert query with reference to the selected checkbox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 $uread = 0;$uwrite = 0; $usearch = 0; 

 if(isset($_POST[perm[0]])==1)
    $uread = 1;
 if(isset($_POST[perm[1]])==1)
    $uwrite = 1;
 if(isset($_POST[perm[2]])==1)
    $usearch = 1;


Insert into `your-tbl-name`(uname,uwrite,usearch) values ($uread,$write,$usearch);
```

Answer (score 0):

From brief information you have provide,I expect this may fulfill your requirement

```
     $uread = 0;$uwrite = 0; $usearch = 0; // User have not checked any thing and 0=unchecked,1=checked

     if(isset($_POST[perm[0]]))
        $uread = 1;
     if(isset($_POST[perm[1]]))
        $uwrite = 1;
     if(isset($_POST[perm[2]]))
        $usearch = 1;

//NOW insert statement    
Insert into `your-tbl-name`(uname,uwrite,usearch) values ($uread,$write,$usearch);
```

Modify `insert statement` according to your requirement.